# XMl with Namespace Parse php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap

I am trying to parse the xml below with namespaces and im requesting your assistance on this

```
How do i extract the values in it?

this is what i have so far.

$source = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <req:ResponseMsg><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns="http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/response">
    <ResponseCode>20000003</ResponseCode>
    <ResponseDesc>Internal Server Error</ResponseDesc>
</response>]]></req:ResponseMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$element = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

$element->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$element->registerXPathNamespace('req','http://api-v1.gen.mm.vodafone.com/mminterface/request');

var_dump($element->xpath('//req:ResponseMsg'));
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to make an attempt yourself first of all. We are not here to do your basic research for you.

Comment: i have updated.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: what i want is to extract the node values ResponseCode and ResponseDesc